# Помогите решить ошибку пожалуйста?

Tags: python

Когда я пишу команду рег то бот отвечает вы уже зарегистрированы но меня нету в базе данных и потом я пишу деньги то бот пишет вы не зарегистрированы что бы зарегистрироваться напишите рег,как исправить? и что делать?,как сделать что бы человек занёсся в базу данных?,бд Sqlite бот для вконтакте беседы лонгполл

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('plugins/db/dasebate.db')
cur = conn.cursor()

def register(user_id):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('plugins/db/dasebate.db')
    try:
        result = cur.execute(f'SELECT * FROM profile WHERE uid={user_id}')
        if result == 0:
            cur.execute(f'INSERT INTO profile(uid) VALUES({user_id})')
            conn.commit()
            return 'Вы успешно зарегистрировались!'

        else:
            return 'Вы уже зарегистрировались!'


    finally:
        conn.close()

def check_balance(user_id):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('plugins/db/dasebate.db')
    try:
        result = cur.execute(f'SELECT * FROM profile WHERE uid={user_id}')
        row = cur.fetchone()
        if result == 1:
            return row['balance']

        else:
            return 'Вы не зарегистрированы, что бы зарегистрироваться напишите "рег"'


    finally:
        conn.close()

вот основной код:
elif event.obj['message']['text'].lower().startswith("лео рег"):
              text = register(event.obj['message']['peer_id'])
              vk.messages.send(peer_id=event.obj['message']['peer_id'], message={text}, random_id=random.randint(-1000000000, 1000000000))

        elif event.obj['message']['text'].lower().startswith("лео деньги"):
            text = check_balance(event.obj['message']['peer_id'])
            vk.messages.send(peer_id=event.obj['message']['peer_id'], message=f'Ваш баланс: {text}',random_id=random.randint(-1000000000, 1000000000))
```

Comment: С чего вы взяли, что `cur.execute(f'SELECT * FROM profile WHERE uid={user_id}')` может возвращать 0? И кто научил вас использовать интерполяцию строк для формирования запросов?

Comment: На ютубе нашёл видео

Comment: Ааа, понятно. Вы учитесь по материалам низкого качества, естественно, что у вас возникают подобные проблемы.

Comment: А как их решить?